# Combing Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I made a parrot logo for an project and I want it to build before loading a basic trivia game I also made.

Whenever the image builds it closes when it finishes, I am unsure of how to make this work.

```dos
@echo off 
cls 
echo LOADING GAME... 
ping localhost -n 5 >nul 
@echo off 

:loop 
:menu 
cls 
color 0b 
echo Trivia Game 
ping localhost -n 5 >nul 

color 0e 
:loop 
:menu 
echo Made by River Davis 

echo=================================================================================
echo 1)Start 
echo 2)Options/Info 
echo 3)exit 
echo=================================================================================
set /p hi= 

if not defined hi ( 
cls 
goto loop 
) 

if %hi% == 1 goto Game 
if %hi% == 2 goto Options/Info 
if %hi% == 3 exit 

:menu1 
cls 
color 0b 
echo Trvia Game 
ping localhost -n 5 >nul 

color 0a 
:loop 
:menu 
echo Made by River Davis

echo=================================================================================
echo 1)Start 
echo 2)Options/Info 
echo 3)exit 
echo=================================================================================
set /p hi= 

if not defined hi ( 
cls 
goto loop 
) 

if %hi% == 1 goto Game 
if %hi% == 2 goto Options/Info 
if %hi% == 3 exit 

:menu2 
cls 
color 0b 
echo Trivia Game 
ping localhost -n 5 >nul 

color 0b 
:loop 
:menu 
echo Made by River Davis 

echo=================================================================================
echo 1)Start 
echo 2)Options/Info 
echo 3)exit 
echo=================================================================================
set /p hi= 

if not defined hi ( 
cls 
goto loop 
) 

if %hi% == 1 goto Game 
if %hi% == 2 goto Options/Info 
if %hi% == 3 exit 

:menu3 
cls 
color 0b 
echo Trivia Game 
ping localhost -n 5 >nul 

color 0c 
:loop 
:menu 
echo Made by River Davis 

echo================================================================================= 
echo 1)Start 
echo 2)Options/Info 
echo 3)exit 
echo=================================================================================
set /p hi= 

if not defined hi ( 
cls 
goto loop 
) 

if %hi% == 1 goto Game 
if %hi% == 2 goto Options/Info 
if %hi% == 3 exit 

:menu4 
cls 
color 0b 
echo Trivia Game 
ping localhost -n 5 >nul 

color 0d 
:loop 
:menu 
echo Made by River Davis 

echo=================================================================================
echo 1)Start 
echo 2)Options/Info 
echo 3)exit 
echo=================================================================================
set /p hi= 

if not defined hi ( 
cls 
goto loop 
) 

if %hi% == 1 goto Game 
if %hi% == 2 goto Options/Info 
if %hi% == 3 exit 

:menu5 
cls 
color 0b 
echo Trivia Game 
ping localhost -n 5 >nul 

color 0f 
:loop 
:menu 
echo Made by River Davis 

echo=================================================================================
echo 1)Start 
echo 2)Options/Info 
echo 3)exit 
echo=================================================================================  
set /p hi= 

if not defined hi ( 
cls 
goto loop 
) 

if %hi% == 1 goto Game 
if %hi% == 2 goto Options/Info 
if %hi% == 3 exit 

:game 
cls 
echo What's Your Name? 
set /p name= 
echo Hello %name%! Would you like to start (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl1 
if %start% == Y goto lvl1 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 

:Options/Info 
cls 
echo============================ 
echo This game was made for 
echo Mrs.Crosby's class by
echo River Davis in 2016
echo============================ 
echo choose a Menu Colour 
echo colours=0a,Light Green/ 0b,Light Aqua/ 0c,Light Red/ 0d,Light purple/ 
echo 0e,Light Yellow/ 0f,White 
set /p color= 
%color% 

if %color%== 0a goto menu1 
if %color%== 0b goto menu2 
if %color%== 0c goto menu3 
if %color%== 0d goto menu4 
if %color%== 0e goto menu 
if %color%== 0f goto menu5 

:lvl1 
cls 
echo Question 1)
echo what does 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 equal 
echo a.45 
echo b.50 
echo c.62 
echo d.55 
set /p ha= 

if %ha% == a goto crl 
if %ha% == b goto wrl 
if %ha% == c goto wrl 
if %ha% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl1 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p ha= 

if %ha% == y goto lvl2 
if %ha% == Y goto lvl2 
if %ha% == n goto lvl1 
if %ha% == N goto lvl1 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl1 
if %start% == Y goto lvl1 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 

:lvl2 
cls 
echo Question 2)
echo which planet is the 5th from the sun? 
echo a.Venus 
echo b.Jupiter 
echo c.Uranus 
echo d.Earth 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto crl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl2 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl3 
if %hi% == Y goto lvl3 
if %hi% == n goto lvl2 
if %hi% == N goto lvl2 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl2 
if %start% == Y goto lvl2 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 
@echo off 

:lvl3 
cls 
echo Question 3) 
echo which of the following colours has the most pigments? 
echo a.Blue 
echo b.Orange 
echo c.Brown 
echo d.Red 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto crl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl3 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl4 
if %hi% == Y goto lvl4 
if %hi% == n goto lvl3 
if %hi% == N goto lvl3 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl3 
if %start% == Y goto lvl3 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 
@echo off 

:lvl4 
cls 
echo Question 4)
echo who was the first man launched in to space? 
echo a.Mike Collins 
echo b.Neil Armstrong 
echo c.Yuri gagarin 
echo d.Buzz Aldrin 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto crl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl4 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl5 
if %hi% == Y goto lvl5 
if %hi% == n goto lvl4 
if %hi% == N goto lvl4 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl4 
if %start% == Y goto lvl4 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 
@echo off 

:lvl5 
cls 
echo Question 5)
echo Who was the Original owner of Apple? 
echo a.Steve Jobs 
echo b.Bill Gates 
echo c.Jeorge Lucas 
echo d.Harry Potter 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto crl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl5 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl6 
if %hi% == Y goto lvl6 
if %hi% == n goto lvl5 
if %hi% == N goto lvl5 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl5 
if %start% == Y goto lvl5 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 
@echo off 

:lvl6 
cls 
echo Question 6)
echo Which of these deceased singers was assasinated? 
echo a. Freddie Mercury 
echo b. John Lennon 
echo c. Elvis Presley 
echo d. Michael Jackson 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto crl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl7 
if %hi% == Y goto lvl7 
if %hi% == n goto lvl6 
if %hi% == N goto lvl6 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl6 
if %start% == Y goto lvl6 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 
@echo off 

:lvl7 
cls 
echo Question 7)
echo Who created the first light bulb? 
echo a. Thomas Edison 
echo b. Hiram Stevens 
echo c. Joseph Swan 
echo d. Albert Einstein 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto crl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl8 
if %hi% == Y goto lvl8 
if %hi% == n goto lvl7 
if %hi% == N goto lvl7 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl7 
if %start% == Y goto lvl7 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu 
goto start game 
@echo off 

:lvl8 
cls 
echo Question 8)
echo how old was Sir Edmund Hillary when he died? 
echo a. 79 
echo b. 92 
echo c. 86 
echo d. 88 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto crl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl9 
if %hi% == Y goto lvl9 
if %hi% == n goto lvl8 
if %hi% == N goto lvl8 
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl8 
if %start% == Y goto lvl8 
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu
goto start game 
@echo off 

:lvl9 
cls 
echo Question 9)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto crl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl10
if %hi% == Y goto lvl10
if %hi% == n goto lvl9
if %hi% == N goto lvl9
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl9 
if %start% == Y goto lvl9
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl10
cls 
echo Question 10)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto crl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl11
if %hi% == Y goto lvl11
if %hi% == n goto lvl10
if %hi% == N goto lvl10
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl10
if %start% == Y goto lvl10
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl11
cls 
echo Question 11)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto crl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl12
if %hi% == Y goto lvl12
if %hi% == n goto lvl11
if %hi% == N goto lvl11
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl11
if %start% == Y goto lvl11
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu  

:lvl12
cls 
echo Question 12)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto crl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl13
if %hi% == Y goto lvl13
if %hi% == n goto lvl12
if %hi% == N goto lvl12
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl12
if %start% == Y goto lvl12
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl13
cls 
echo Question 13)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto crl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl14
if %hi% == Y goto lvl14
if %hi% == n goto lvl13
if %hi% == N goto lvl13
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl13
if %start% == Y goto lvl13
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl14
cls 
echo Question 14)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl 
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto crl 
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl15
if %hi% == Y goto lvl15
if %hi% == n goto lvl14
if %hi% == N goto lvl14
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl14
if %start% == Y goto lvl14
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl15
cls 
echo Question 15)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl
if %hi% == c goto crl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl16
if %hi% == Y goto lvl16
if %hi% == n goto lvl15
if %hi% == N goto lvl15
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl15
if %start% == Y goto lvl15
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl16
cls 
echo Question 16)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto crl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl17
if %hi% == Y goto lvl17
if %hi% == n goto lvl16
if %hi% == N goto lvl16
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl16
if %start% == Y goto lvl16
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl17
cls 
echo Question 17)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto crl
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl18
if %hi% == Y goto lvl18
if %hi% == n goto lvl17
if %hi% == N goto lvl17
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl17
if %start% == Y goto lvl17
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl18
cls 
echo Question 18)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto crl
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl19
if %hi% == Y goto lvl19
if %hi% == n goto lvl18
if %hi% == N goto lvl18
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl18
if %start% == Y goto lvl18
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl19
cls 
echo Question 19)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto wrl
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto crl
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %hi% == y goto lvl20
if %hi% == Y goto lvl20
if %hi% == n goto lvl19
if %hi% == N goto lvl19
goto crl 

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl19
if %start% == Y goto lvl19
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu

:lvl20
cls 
echo Question 20)
echo INSERT QUESTION HERE 
echo a. ANS 
echo b. ANS
echo c. ANS 
echo d. ANS 
set /p hi= 

if %hi% == a goto wrl 
if %hi% == b goto crl
if %hi% == c goto wrl 
if %hi% == d goto wrl
goto lvl6 

:crl 
echo Correct! Thanks For Playing! :)
pause
goto menu

:wrl 
echo wrong 
echo . 
pause 
cls 
echo Retry? (y/n) 
set /p start= 

if %start% == y goto lvl20
if %start% == Y goto lvl20
if %start% == n goto menu 
if %start% == N goto menu


@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set q=^"
echo(
echo(
call :c 0E "                ,      .-;" /n
call :c 0E "             ,  |\    / /  __," /n
call :c 0E "             |\ '.`-.|  |.'.-'" /n
call :c 0E "              \`'-:  `; : /" /n
call :c 0E "               `-._'.  \'|" /n
call :c 0E "              ,_.-=` ` `  ~,_" /n
call :c 0E "               '--,.    "&call :c 0c ".-. "&call :c 0E ",=!q!." /n
call :c 0E "                 /     "&call :c 0c "{ "&call :c 0A "* "&call :c 0c ")"&call :c 0E "`"&call :c 06 ";-."&call :c 0E "}" /n
call :c 0E "                 |      "&call :c 0c "'-' "&call :c 06 "/__ |" /n
call :c 0E "                 /          "&call :c 06 "\_,\|" /n
call :c 0E "                 |          (" /n
call :c 0E "             "&call :c 0c "__ "&call :c 0E "/ '          \" /n
call :c 02 "     /\_    "&call :c 0c "/,'`"&call :c 0E "|     '   "&call :c 0c ".-~!q!~~-." /n
call :c 02 "     |`.\_ "&call :c 0c "|   "&call :c 0E "/  ' ,    "&call :c 0c "/        \" /n
call :c 02 "   _/  `, \"&call :c 0c "|  "&call :c 0E "; ,     . "&call :c 0c "|  ,  '  . |" /n
call :c 02 "   \   `,  "&call :c 0c "|  "&call :c 0E "|  ,  ,   "&call :c 0c "|  :  ;  : |" /n
call :c 02 "   _\  `,  "&call :c 0c "\  "&call :c 0E "|.     ,  "&call :c 0c "|  |  |  | |" /n
call :c 02 "   \`  `.   "&call :c 0c "\ "&call :c 0E "|   '     "&call :c 0A "|"&call :c 0c "\_|-'|_,'\|" /n
call :c 02 "   _\   `,   "&call :c 0A "`"&call :c 0E "\  '  . ' "&call :c 0A "| |  | |  |           "&call :c 02 "__" /n
call :c 02 "   \     `,   "&call :c 0E "| ,  '    "&call :c 0A "|_/'-|_\_/     "&call :c 02 "__ ,-;` /" /n
call :c 02 "    \    `,    "&call :c 0E "\ .  , ' .| | | | |   "&call :c 02 "_/' ` _=`|" /n
call :c 02 "     `\    `,   "&call :c 0E "\     ,  | | | | |"&call :c 02 "_/'   .=!q!  /" /n
call :c 02 "     \`     `,   "&call :c 0E "`\      \/|,| ;"&call :c 02 "/'   .=!q!    |" /n
call :c 02 "      \      `,    "&call :c 0E "`\' ,  | ; "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!    _/" /n
call :c 02 "       `\     `,  "&call :c 05 ".-!q!!q!-. "&call :c 0E "': "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!     /" /n
call :c 02 "       _`\    ;"&call :c 05 "_{  '   ; "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!      /" /n
call :c 02 "       _\`-/__"&call :c 05 ".~  `."&call :c 07 "8"&call :c 05 ".'.!q!`~-. "&call :c 02 "=!q!     _,/" /n
call :c 02 "    __\      "&call :c 05 "{   '-."&call :c 07 "|"&call :c 05 ".'.--~'`}"&call :c 02 "    _/" /n
call :c 02 "    \    .=!q!` "&call :c 05 "}.-~!q!'"&call :c 0D "u"&call :c 05 "'-. '-..'  "&call :c 02 "__/" /n
call :c 02 "   _/  .!q!    "&call :c 05 "{  -'.~('-._,.'"&call :c 02 "\_,/" /n
call :c 02 "  /  .!q!    _/'"&call :c 05 "`--; ;  `.  ;" /n
call :c 02 "   .=!q!  _/'      "&call :c 05 "`-..__,-'" /n
call :c 02 "    __/'" /n
echo(

exit /b

:c
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "s=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 s %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined DEL call :initColorPrint
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd .
':
cd \
set "s=!%~2!"
:: The single blank line within the following IN() clause is critical - DO NOT REMOVE
for %%n in (^"^

^") do (
  set "s=!s:\=%%~n\%%~n!"
  set "s=!s:/=%%~n/%%~n!"
  set "s=!s::=%%~n:%%~n!"
)
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%s in ("!s!") do (
  if "!" equ "" setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  if %%s==\ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else if %%s==/ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "/.\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else (
    >colorPrint.txt (echo %%s\..\')
    findstr /a:%~1 /f:colorPrint.txt "."
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  )
)
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
popd
exit /b


:initColorPrint
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H&for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%A %%A"
<nul >"%temp%\'" set /p "=."
subst ': "%temp%" >nul
exit /b


:cleanupColorPrint
2>nul del "%temp%\'"
2>nul del "%temp%\colorPrint.txt"
>nul subst ': /d
exit /b
```

I need the parrot to load first then the quiz, and every time I try combing them none of what I have tried has worked.

Comment: I do not see any code at the beginning of your script to CALL the code to create the parrot image.  Nor do you have a label with your image code for the CALL to find.

Comment: Please read this help article and adapt your question accordingly then: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Go through your script again and make sure you don't have multiple labels with the same name, having seven :loop and seven :menu with some goto's is just wrong.